# Node + Express JS API is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm a beginner in node.js but I try a little harder to setup a structure in node + express js.I start doing with the front-end and separate API structure.I put a single app.js for both API and front-end.But my API is not working. it gives error Cannot GET /api/users when i call http://localhost:3000/api/users. please help

```
api
-controllers
-helpers
-middlewares
-models
-routes.js
app.js
controllers
helpers
middlewares
models
node_modules
package.json
public
views
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  , port = process.env.PORT || 3000

var path = require('path');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(require('./controllers'))
var routes = require('./api/routes');
app.use('/api', routes);
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port)
})
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express')
 , router = express.Router()
var usersController = require('./controllers/users');
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/users', usersController.getUser);
};
module.exports = router;
```

users.js(controller)

```
module.exports = {
    getUser: function (req, res) {
        console.log("sdfdsfdsfsd");
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify({"msg": "welcome user"}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is an example on how to set up express in nodejs, you may find useful: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Answer (score 1):

In your `routes.js` file you are exporting two things. Try to only export the router

```
var express = require('express')
 , router = express.Router()
var usersController = require('./controllers/users');

router.get('/users', usersController.getUser);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: thanks mate. according to you i'm importing two things can you tell me more brief which things i'm importing wrong.

Comment: Not importing, exporting. You are exporting both `module.exports = router;` and `module.exports = function (app) { ...}`.  Try to do as detailed in my answer : only export the router and replace `app.get` by `router.get`

Comment: var express = require('express')
 , router = express.Router()
var usersController = require('./controllers/users');
module.exports = function (app) {
    router.get('/users', usersController.getUser);
}; it is also not working why

Comment: Use the code from my answer above please. `var express = require('express')
 , router = express.Router()
var usersController = require('./controllers/users');

router.get('/users', usersController.getUser);

module.exports = router;`

Comment: Your code work well. i'm just exploring my knowledge. thanks